# file transfer via ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm searching for an option to transfer a zip-file via ROS. Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165126/file-transfer-via-ros/) by [LetThemDance](https://answers.ros.org/users/3116/letthemdance/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This really sounds like you're looking for a linux file-transfer tool such as scp or rsync.

I suppose you could define a new message type, probably with a string field for the file name and byte[] field for the raw data, and publish that on a topic.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0