# Using ROS 2 to transfer files in a periodic comms denied environment

Tags: ros2, communication, filesystem

Are there any existing packages or functionality for transferring files using ROS2/DDS for reliable communication?  Recommended workflow or solution architectures (e.g. "just use sockets because..") would also be helpful.

In particular I am thinking of a usecase where wireless bandwidth is periodically reduced or denied for a portion of my system (e.g. a robot goes on a mission outside of comms and then returns for a short period of time with some compressed dataset before going back out).

I am aware of [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/59392/38023) but was hoping something had been developed in the past 10 years. Perhaps this is a niche usecase though.